# Convert parametric equations to Cartesian

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

I took a quiz today on parametric equations, and there was this one problem that I could not figure out. The question asked me to find $y$ in terms of $x$.

$$x = t^2 - t$$
$$y = t - 1$$

The first thing I tried was solving for $t$ in terms of $x$

$$x = t^2 - t$$
$$ x + t = t^2$$
$$t = \sqrt{x+t}$$

The above didn't work.

I then tried solving for t in terms of y, and then plugging that in for $t$

$$t = y + 1$$
$$x = (y+1)^2 - (y+1)$$
$$x = (y+1)(y+1) - y - 1$$
$$x = y^2 + y + y + 1 - y - 1$$
$$x = y^2 + 2y + 1 - y - 1$$
$$x = y^2 + y$$

That is where I get stuck. Would I have to find the inverse of $x = y^2 + y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the quadratic formula to get
$$y=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+x}$$